# div overlays youtube video using z-index?

Tags: html, css, iframe, z-index

i am trying to put an html element -that i want to use to close it- over a video iframe,

trying with

```
#close{
     position:absolute;
     top:50px;
     z-index:9999;
}
```

but it won't work. the iframe is always on top,

also tried to add

`&wmode=opaque` to the URL... but nothing

You can see/test here: http://jsfiddle.net/fdsaP/467/

Any idea what am i missing???  or it's just not posible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible. Solved it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vyder/fdsaP/506/

Essentially, you do need to set the window mode to opaque. But you need to set the option by appending `?wmode=opaque` at the end of the video id, but *before* any other parameters.